# How to retrive and show captured image in a image panel using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, camera, sencha-touch-2

I have developed a secha toucha application and I want to use camera feature in that using Phonegap. Using phonegap I am able to access the device camera and capture photo. But when I click "use" button  of camera after captyring photo, it supposed to be stored in a image panel. But noting is happening. Here is my code. Please help, I am really stuck !!

```
onRegisterMain: function () {
     this.hidefn();
    modelMgr.campentry = this.getEntry();
   Ext.getCmp('cdcamptitle').hide();/*neetu hide*/
    Ext.getCmp('userLogo').setHtml("<figure> <img src='img/imgDnr.png'  alt='WIPRO_BLOOD_BANK'/></figure>");

       Ext.getCmp('userLogo').on({
                                 tap: function () {

                                 navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL});

                                 function onSuccess(imageData) {
                                 var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                                 image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                                 }


                                // console.log('tapped')
                                 // this.pieChartDisplay();

                                 },
                                 scope: this
                                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your destinationType is referencing the file's URL whereas your success function is looking for base64 data. Simply removing the destinationType will default to base64:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50});
```